# Should I pass function objects by value or by reference?

Tags: rust

There seems to be two ways to pass functions as arguments which don't do dynamic dispatch:

1. `&impl Fn(TIn) -> TOut // By reference`
2. `impl Fn(TIn) -> TOut  // By value`

Assuming the function is pure (i.e. can be called multiple times), my initial thoughts were that the best way is to pass by reference. This means a function object can be used more than once (as ownership isn't transferred), and in the more common case where it's just an anonymous closure, the reference indirection should be optimised away because the compiler knows exactly the function itself (so it can just be inlined).

However, I've noticed `Option::map` for example, passes it's closure by value, which made me think maybe I was doing something wrong.

Should I pass function objects by value or by reference? If there's no clear answer either way, what are the factors I should consider?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You should use `F: Fn() -> ()` or `impl Fn() -> ()` as an argument.

## `Fn`

As @Bubletan mentioned [in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56420814/147192), the key point is that `Fn` is [automatically implemented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html#implementors) for `&F` if `F` implements `Fn`:

```
impl<'_, A, F> Fn<A> for &'_ F
where
    F: Fn<A> + ?Sized,
```

The consequence is that:

- `foo(f: impl Fn() -> ())` can be called *both* with `foo(callable)` or `foo(&callable)`.
- `foo(f: &impl Fn() -> ())` *forces* the caller to use `foo(&callable)` and disallow `foo(callable)`.

In general, it is best to leave the choice to the caller when there is downside for the callee, and therefore the first form should be preferred.

## `FnMut`

The same logic applies to `FnMut`, which is also [automatically implemented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html#implementors) for `&mut F` if `F` implements `FnMut`:

```
impl<'_, A, F> FnMut<A> for &'_ mut F
where
    F: FnMut<A> + ?Sized,
```

Which should therefore also be passed by value in arguments, leaving the choice to the caller as to whether they prefer `foo(callable)` or `foo(&mut callable)`.

## `FnOnce`

There is the argument of consistency with `FnOnce`, which can only be passed by value, which again points into the direction of taking arguments of the `Fn*` family by value.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that `Option::map` takes a closure by value, is that it has the [following signature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/option.rs.html#412-417):

```rust
pub fn map<U, F: FnOnce(T) -> U>(self, f: F) -> Option<U>
```

This therefore means that it *needs* to take it by value, because the definition of `FnOnce` is the [following](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/ops/function.rs.html#224-232):

```rust
pub trait FnOnce<Args> {
    type Output;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: Args) -> Self::Output;
}
```

Also, this `Fn` variant is the least restrictive, and therefore the most usable, because `FnMut: FnOnce` and `Fn: FnMut`, so `FnOnce` is the least derived.
So, from this we can infer:

- `Option::map` is trying to make its arguments the least restrictive
- `FnOnce` is the least restrictive
- `FnOnce` needs to take `self` by value
- Therefore `Option::map` takes `f` by value because otherwise [it'd be useless](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=17ee7d675623671843f0115a5b44fa80).

Comment: The fact that `FnOnce` consumes self also means that if you require that, your function can only be used once, even if it is a `Fn`, right? That also seems restrictive

Comment: @harmic that the opposite "Since both Fn and FnMut are subtraits of FnOnce, any instance of Fn or FnMut can be used where a FnOnce is expected."

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of the [Fn](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html) trait states that if some type F implements Fn, then &F also implements Fn.

In the documentation of the [Copy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) trait, it is mentioned that the trait is automatically implemented for function pointers and closures (depending on what they capture of course). That is, they are copied when passed as a parameter to a function.

Therefore you should go with the second option.

An example:

```
fn foo(f: impl Fn(i32) -> i32) -> i32 { f(42) }

fn bar() {
    let f = |x| -> 2 * x;
    foo(f);
    foo(f); // f is copied and can thus be used
}
```

Comment: I'm still not clear why I would go for the second option over the first? You stated: "if some type F implements Fn, then &F also implements Fn." You haven't said that if &F implements Fn then F implements Fn, so that statement tends to imply that &F is the more general approach.

Comment: @Clinton What I meant by that, was that if you had a reference, you could still pass it without dereferencing. In the other case, if you required a reference, you would have to create one in case you had a non-reference. In the example given in the answer, you would have to pass `&f` instead.

Comment: I'm still not understanding why you're suggesting the by value approach. All you've seemed to say is that _most_ of the time `Fn`s a copyable, but it seems to me that passing by reference works all the time. If you point out a downside to option 1 I might understand why option 2 is the better approach.

Comment: @Clinton The downside is forced indirection. Like I said, you would have to write `&f` instead of just `f`. If you have &F that implements Fn, you can still pass it just as it is.